# Mount Second Partition on Android Device with vold

Tags: android, mount, automount

I want to have access to an ext4 partition, without using Data2SD yet, on the SD card of my HTC Vision running the Virtuous Unity 1.3.0 ROM. I modded my `/system/etc/vold.fstab` file from this:

```
dev_mount sdcard /mnt/sdcard auto /devices/platform/goldfish_mmc.0 
/devices/platform/msm_sdcc.4/mmc_host/mmc2
```

To this:

```
#dev_mount sdcard /mnt/sdcard auto /devices/platform/goldfish_mmc.0 
/devices/platform/msm_sdcc.4/mmc_host/mmc2

dev_mount sdcard /mnt/sdcard 1 /devices/platform/goldfish_mmc.0 /devices/platform/msm_sdcc.4/mmc_host/mmc2

dev_mount e4vol /mnt/sdcard2 2 /devices/platform/goldfish_mmc.0 
/devices/platform/msm_sdcc.4/mmc_host/mmc2
```

So I can get my second partition, with label e4vol, mount and usable on my Android device. Two issues, and I think one obviously has to do with the other.

1. I have tried remounting the root read-write and creating the mount point `/mnt/sdcard2`, but it is gone on reboot. Seems like Android might have in the past created such mounts with `mount.conf`. Now it does not exist on Gingerbread ROMS. Thoughts?
2. Is this all I would have to do to get my second partition mounted in Android, or do I also need to create `/sdcard2` like `/sdcard`? I presume both are created as symlinks by vold as specified in this conf file, but I have not had time to check yet.

I would ask forums, but this seems like a developer question and this is the most recent release of the OS. It seems to change a lot from version to version of the OS. Thanks in advance for your patience and help.

**UPDATE:** So, moved the test mount to sdcard, and it did not work, even with a persistent mount point. So, not sure where I am going wrong.

Comment: http://www.link2sd.info/faq You will find most of your answers on this link

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you'll have to have a look into /init.rc.

There are some "mkdir /mnt/..."-statements. You only have to add your "mkdir /mnt/sdcard2" and "ln -s /mnt/sdcard2 /sdcard2" to this file.

But be careful when editing this file!!!

Comment: init.rc is restored afer reboot.

Answer (score 0):

I looked at the vold source up to including Icecream-Sandwich: it’s final mount() system call is hardcoded to the “vfat” file system type. – Even if you get it to try the mount, it would fail.

I myself actually want to mount my ext4 SD card to /sdcard, because I regularly suffer from SD card FAT file system corruptions (and I’m not the only one having those with Android).

The alternative is: modify the init/boot process to just mount the partition where you want, bypassing vold.